# Spring annotation configuration replacement for web.xml configuration

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations

I want to replace the configuration of spring contexts in web.xml by an annotation based configuration.

What is the best approach to keep the configuration the same way it is, but no more the separate xml config files in web.xml.

Currently each listed context is loaded after each other, to have some "boot phases". 
Then there are context files that fill the application context (shared by every servlet) and servlet specific xml configuration files.

The starting point should be a single reference in web.xml to the initial RootContext java class with @Configuration annotation. But how to proceed then, to keep the separate contexts, as they are now?

Here the current web.xml snippet:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/2nd-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/3rd-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/4th-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springWebapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/servlet/servlet-context1.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/servlet/servlet-context2.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

I'm very grateful for help.

Comment: Though not a direct answer but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983613/implementing-applicationcontextaware-applicationcontext-is-null) post has pretty comprehensive java based config which can be reffered.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/2nd-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/3rd-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/4th-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

By

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
  "classpath:WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml",
  "classpath:WEB-INF/spring/2nd-context.xml",
  "classpath:WEB-INF/spring/3rd-context.xml",
  "classpath:WEB-INF/spring/4th-context.xml"
})
public class AppConfig {
}
```

OR you can separate configs into separate classes and importClass in AppConfig.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
  "classpath:WEB-INF/spring/2nd-context.xml",
  "classpath:WEB-INF/spring/3rd-context.xml",
  "classpath:WEB-INF/spring/4th-context.xml"

})
public class AppSecondConfig {
}

@Configuration
@ImportResource({
  "classpath:WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml"
})
@Import(AppSecondConfig.class)
public class AppConfig {
}
```

EDIT: For multiple imports in order -  @Import({ AppSecondConfig.class, AppThirdConfig.class })

Replace

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springWebapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/servlet/servlet-context1.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/servlet/servlet-context2.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

By

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
  "classpath:WEB-INF/spring/servlet/servlet-context1.xml",
  "classpath:WEB-INF/spring/servlet/servlet-context2.xml"
})
public class ServletConfig {
}
```

And tell your web.xml now to refer the config classes like this

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>
       org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com...config.AppConfig</param-value>
  </context-param>

 <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring-mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
          <param-value>
              org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
          </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>com....config.ServletConfig</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Comment: Do you think the order of the context classes will be kept with that approach? Meening that RootContext will be loaded as first completely, afterwards AppSecondConfig, afterwards AppThirdConfig.

Comment: If you want multiple imports in order, you can do this @Import({ AppSecondConfig.class, AppThirdConfig.class })

Comment: For multiple configuration classes [spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s03.html)    [spring doc2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)